# Wordpress Database Memory Error

Tags: mysql, php, wordpress

I'm running a large Wordpress multisite install that, for each site, runs a number of database queries to display information in the respective blog. The data queries aren't too heavy however I often see this in my error log:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 1572864000 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 97 bytes) in /home/********/public_html/wp-includes/wp-db.php on line 1775
```

When this occurs I believe the page being called (that causes the error) stops loading and the user has to reload to access the information. I've been through every page being called an all load on their own without any issue.

Looking at the relevant line in the wp-db.php file this is the line that causes the error:

```
preg_match( '/^\s*(create|alter|truncate|drop)\s/i', $query ) ) {
            $return_val = $this->result;
```

i.e. when a database query is being executed. Something is obviously going quite wrong here as I've tried upping my memory limit for php resources. Does anyone know how I would go about identifying what is causing this error so I can fix it?

Comment: I would start by looking in the system logs

Comment: What happens if you allocate more memory to each PHP process?

Comment: Every time i allocate more memory via define( ‘WP_MEMORY_LIMIT’, xyz ); this new memory limit is just eaten up and the error continues, it seems there is no ceiling to the memory being used. Should i be allocating memory to each task and then clearing it somehow?

Comment: `WP_MEMORY_LIMIT` does not allocate more memory. It just tells wordpress (and nothing else) how much memory it can use. You should decrease this value, not increase it. PHP and Apache memory limits have to be configured in their respective config files in /etc, you can increase the memory limit there.